# How to create dynamic tabs and viewController using CarbonKit in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have used a carbon kit for tabs. Right now I have given tabs in static but from API there, two more tabs are added and which may vary. How to create dynamic tabs with one viewcontroller.

here is the code used for one tab viewcontroller:

```
  carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: ["Basic Details"], delegate: self)
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self, andTargetView: infoView)
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setSelectedColor(UIColor.black)
    carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setIndicatorColor(UIColor(hexString: "#363794"))


   public init() {

         super.init(nibName: "CreateCardViewController", bundle: Bundle(for: CreateCardViewController.self))
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

     }

public func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {


    return firstView()
   }
func firstView() -> UIViewController {



    let cont = WebViewController()
    self.tabContView?.addChild(cont)
    self.tabContView?.view.addSubview(cont.view)

    cont.didMove(toParent: tabContView)
    let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authToken")

    cont.formKey = formKey
    print("cont vl", formKey ?? "")
    cont.processInstanceId = processInstanceId
    cont.authTokenValue = authToken
    cont.fullFormKey = fullFormKey
    cont.taskIdValue = TaskIdValue
    return cont

}
```

how to create a dynamic tab with single viewController using carbonKit? Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: have you check my answer? If it's helpful to you then please accept and upvote it so another user find it's as helpful who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of string from your API response or model, then assign it to `CarbonTabSwipeNavigation` to create a dynamic tab.

```
var carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation()
var arrItems = ["Eid Special", "Super Offer", "4G Device"] 

func initCarbonKitTab() {

        //arrItems is an array of string that you will create from API response

        carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: arrItems, delegate: self)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self, andTargetView: infoView)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setSelectedColor(UIColor.black)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setIndicatorColor(UIColor(hexString: "#363794"))
}
```

you can call the above function as per your need like after API response.

```
self.initCarbonKitTab()
```

And then you can use an array of string or index to show a view controller for a specific tab or index.

```
func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {

    if index == 0 {
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:”ViewControllerA”) as!  ViewControllerA
        return vc 
    }            
    else {
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:”ViewControllerB”) as!  ViewControllerB
        return vc 
    }
 }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: but how can i create dynamic viewcontroller/

Comment: you can use the conditions to show different view controllers in `viewControllerAt index` delegate method.

Comment: I confusing at dynamic viewcontroller based on tabs and it should remove automatically if tabs are not available.

Comment: If there are no items in your array of tabs then a carbon kit will not be added and that's why there are no tabs shown.

Comment: How will you get selected index??